# is there a way to check if userinput exists in a textfile?

Tags: python

Part of this program I'm making requires the user input (username) and checks if it already exists in a textfile. If it already exists, it prints("username already exists.") 
But right now regardless of whether the input already exists in the textfile, the program continues to add the input into the textfile.
Does anyone know how to fix it?(here's that part btw)

```
def passcheck():
    user=name_ent2.get()
    pass1 = pass_ent2.get()
    confirm = retype_ent.get()
    names = open("nlist.txt","a+")
    if user in names:
        print("username already exists.")
    if user not in names:
        names.write(user)
        names.write('\n')
        names.close()
```

is there a way to check if userinput exists in a textfile?

Comment: A file can only be read once, you would need to reset its file pointer to read it again. By the time you try your second `not in names`, the file is at its end and the search for anything in it will be negative, so that condition will always be true. You don't need  to repeat the `if` in its negated form, just use `if..else`.

Comment: Can you please add the txt file so that we can see how the data is stored??

Comment: the textfile gets created as soon as the program runs because i used 'a+' .

Comment: seems more sensible to make `names` a dict, and only write to the file in the end

Answer (score 0):

When you test membership with `user in names`, Python iterates on the lines of the file and compares `user` with each of the lines.

The problem here is that a newline `\n` is included at the end of the line, so your name won't match.

So, you have to strip the lines of this newline before comparing, like:

```
with open('nlist.txt') as names:
    if any(user == line.strip() for line in names):
        print('User exists')
```

Note also that I open the file in read mode (the default, `'r'`). You opened it in append mode, which puts the pointer at the end of the file. As there is nothing more to read, your check would always fail.

Comment: hi! could u explain the second line? why does user==line.strip()?

Comment: `strip()` removes the whitespace and newlines at both ends of the line, and then we compare `user` with the stripped line.

Comment: i see! also, since your lines of code opens the textfile in read mode, if i wanted to add things to the textfile, would i have to add an extra line of code like: names = open("nlist.txt","a+")?

Comment: Yes, you would have to open it again separately, that would be the simplest and safest way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
def passcheck():    
  user=name_ent2.get()
  pass1 = pass_ent2.get()
  confirm = retype_ent.get()
  names = open("nlist.txt","a+")

  paste = bytes(user, 'utf-8')
  with open("nlist.txt", "rb", 0) as file:
    for f in file:
        f = f.strip()
        if f == paste:
            print("true")
            status = True
    if status == False:
        names.write("\n" + user)
        print(user + " got added to the list")
  names.close()
```